# meaning of 一応 at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I was wondering what 一応 would mean in this context. always had trouble grasping the concept of this word.

[image]

Comment: Could you include which episode of which anime this screenshot is from? The preceding dialogue might be useful to know to give a better answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The meaning of 一応 in 一応褒めている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29798/the-meaning-of-%e4%b8%80%e5%bf%9c-in-%e4%b8%80%e5%bf%9c%e8%a4%92%e3%82%81%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b)

Comment: It should be "Hibike! Euphonium" 1x3.

Answer (score 3):

一応 means something is not meeting a high standard, but should largely meet the minimum requirements. Similarly, it's used when something barely manages to qualify as something.

E.g.

- 急に雨が降ってきたので、一応窓だけは閉めておきました（床は見なかったのでまだ濡れているかもしれません）。
- （アルバイトばかりしているのでフリーターだと思われるかもしれませんが）一応大学生です。

It's also used to 謙遜. For example: `一応社長やらせてもらってます` to appear less arrogant compared to just saying `社長やってます`.

Conversely, it can also be associated with indicating that someone has a higher social status (like in this specific case). Here, the 先輩 describes whatever was done for the 後輩 was "一応". This subtly reinforces the relationship between the two.

If the 後輩 would use 「一応」to the 先輩 instead, it shows they are close or have almost equal standing to each other. If not, it would sound rude. E.g. if the 後輩, who just joined the club said 「楽器一応拭いときました」, then it would be rude and 生意気.

Comment: How would you translated your second example? I'd say something like "(Since I just have a part time job people could think of me as a freeter, but) I'm a college student", but I'm not sure how to fit 一応 there; does it have an implication like "And that's the bare minimun to not being a freeter"?

Comment: It's really hard to translate because of the cultural difference. Here, 一応 is added for self-deprecation. So maybe closest I can come up with is: "I may not be a very worthy student, but I am a student nevertheless" (though this sounds way to strong - 一応 is way lighter). @Mauro